# Black screen when Fortnite has to load a fully new screen. Is this a bug or a server error?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

Ever since yesterday afternoon, I have been experiencing a fully black screen when the entire screen turns black and loads for a second or two and then I can see again. This might not be terrible but it has still killed me more than once so it's pretty bad.

I have tried restarting my computer, uninstalling and reinstalling Fortnite, and I have also looked it up to see if someone has experienced the same thing only in Season 8, but I've seen the same kind of thing that others experienced in previous seasons but none in Season 8.

Is this a bug in the game that is causing this black screen or is it a server malfunction because of the high load of people playing right now?

Comment: seems like a common bug a lot of people are experiencing

Comment: Probably won't be fixed until the v8.10 update comes out.

Comment: It's just I haven't seen anyone else experience this

Comment: My Fortnite has been very laggy...It could just be a bug that was fixed, but since the entire world is playing Fortnite, some people are experiencing it

Comment: I feel like it's a server error due to the timing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a *server bug*, if that's a thing.

It mostly happens when there are many people online, around 3:00 PM, and it is when I try to play at that time that it happens most frequently*. This would be a **server error**.

When I tried just now (it's 7:40 AM Eastern Time) it was still happening, though less frequently* and it wasn't affecting me as much, but it still would. This would be a **bug**.

*Frequency determined by going to the same place and determining how many times I get the black screen.

**EDIT:**

The above might still be correct, but a fix to this issue would be to go into Windowed or Windowed Fullscreen because Fullscreen mode causes this issue for some reason.